# jQuery Cycle plugin pauses when clicks on navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery cycle plugin in one of my websites. I have activated the navigation links using pager:  '#slide_pager' option. Now I need to pause the slideshow when clicks on the link. So I have added

```
$('#slide_pager a').click(function(){
         $('#S1').cycle('pause');
      });
```

and my code for slideshow is

```
 $('#S1').cycle({
                fx:    'scrollLeft',
                delay: -2000,
                pager:  '#slide_pager'
        });
```

But when I click on the navigation links, the slideshow is not paused as desired. But if I put the same code for pausing the slideshow on Firebug console and hit run, it is working as desired. So I think the code is right. Please help me to find out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this

$('#S1').cycle({
                fx:    'scrollLeft',
                delay: -2000,
                pager:  '#slide_pager'
        });

$('#slide_pager a').live('click',function(){
         $('#S1').cycle('pause');
      });